# iFrame displaying script code instead of webpage

Tags: html, iframe, moodle, scorm

I have been trying to create an iFrame to display e-Learning materials from a Moodle platform that uses an add on called Scorm to display the material. My problem is that the iFrame doesn't run the Scorm player, it just displays the script's code in the frame instead.

like this:
[image: iframe displaying script]

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
<iframe id="aModule" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

the src of the iframe is changed by a script; i have determined that the script works fine so i'm certain the problem isn't there.

does anybody know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the frame's source have <script> tags? Is it valid HTML? Is it returned with a proper "text/html" content type?

Comment: in all honesty, i have no idea, i don't have access to the source of the frame :/ i will see if one of my colleges does.

Comment: Your browser may present a "View Frame Source" in the context menu (right click). Alternatively you should be able to capture it via the Network tab in the developer tools.